# Legend truncated when saving as pdf using savePlot

Tags: r, plot

I'm using `savePlot` to save charts in several formats. I have a problem with the pdf format: my legend is truncated in the pdf file, but not in the R graph window. I'm on Windows 7. Here's a small example which shows that the legend looks great on screen:

```
win.graph(width=4.375,height=2.8)
par(bty="l",las=1,lwd=1,cex=0.7,oma = c(1, 1, 0, 1), mar = c(3, 4, 3.5, 5))
plot(1:10,type="l")
legend.names <-c("Dividend yield (L)","Core CPI (L)",
    "Dividend yield - core CPI spread (R)")
legend("bottomright", legend=legend.names,  lwd=1, cex=0.7, col =1:3,lty=1:3)
```

But when I try to save the chart as a pdf, the legend gets truncated. The '(R)' at the end is not complete.

```
savePlot(filename = paste("c:/out.pdf",sep=""), type ="pdf")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the size of the pdf?

Comment: I'm using `savePlot` because I need to generate several graphic files. It is easier to plot a chart, and save it in multiple format using `savePlot`. The size of the pdf is the same as called by `win.graph()`

Comment: You probably have different fonts for the win.graph and pdf devices. You can change the defaults.

Comment: @DWIN: Everything is default. I just installed 2.14.1. How should I change the fonts in the pdf device?

Comment: The help page for 'pdfFonts' has a worked example.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is to print straight into a `pdf()` device and not pass through a windows one:

```
pdf(width=4.375, height=2.8, file = "out.pdf")

par(bty="l",las=1,lwd=1,cex=0.7,oma = c(1, 1, 0, 1), mar = c(3, 4, 3.5, 5))
plot(1:10,type="l")
legend.names <-c("Dividend yield (L)","Core CPI (L)",
    "Dividend yield - core CPI spread (R)")
legend("bottomright", legend=legend.names,  lwd=1, cex=0.7, col =1:3,lty=1:3)

dev.off()
```

Comment: As mentioned, I am using `savePlot` because I have to save charts in several formats. You solution would require to repeat plot calls several times. There must be a way to do that with `savePlot`, hence the bounty.

Comment: well, you could wrap the body of the plot code in a function (`tmpplot <- function() { ... }`) which would make this not much harder than using `savePlot`.  But I agree it would be nice if there were a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to the smaller "Helvetica-Narrow" font, use this function that overrides `savePlot()`'s behavior when printing to a pdf:

```
my.savePlot <- function(filename, type) {
   if (type == "pdf") {
      dev.copy(pdf, filename, width  = par("din")[1],
                              height = par("din")[2],
                              family = "Helvetica-Narrow")
      invisible(dev.off())
   } else {
      savePlot(filename, type)
   }
}
```

Comment: This transforms all the text in the chart into "Helvetica-Narrow". I wouldn't mind if it was only the legend.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see what you have to say about this one, maybe third time's a charm! Here, we make use of `recordPlot()` and `replayPlot()` so we can copy the plot into a `pdf()`. Note that the `legend()` call must be wrapped into `recordGraphics()` so it gets recorded in the graphic's display list.

```
my.savePlot <- function(filename, type) {
   if (type == "pdf") {
      saved.plot <- recordPlot()
      pdf(filename, width  = par("din")[1],
                    height = par("din")[2])
      replayPlot(saved.plot)
      invisible(dev.off())
   } else {
      savePlot(filename, type)
   }
}

win.graph(width=4.375,height=2.8)
par(bty="l",las=1,lwd=1,cex=0.7,oma = c(1, 1, 0, 1), mar = c(3, 4, 3.5, 5))
plot(1:10,type="l")
legend.names <-c("Dividend yield (L)","Core CPI (L)",
                 "Dividend yield - core CPI spread (R)")
recordGraphics(legend("bottomright", legend=legend.names,
                      lwd=1, cex=0.7, col =1:3,lty=1:3),
               list(), getNamespace("graphics"))

my.savePlot(filename = paste("out.pdf",sep=""), type ="pdf")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try it this way? It doesn't make problem anymore and you have more control over it.

```
pdf("out.pdf", width=4.375,height=2.8)
par(bty="l",las=1,lwd=1,cex=0.7,oma = c(1, 1, 0, 1), mar = c(3, 4, 3.5, 5))
plot(1:10,type="l")
legend.names <-c("Dividend yield (L)","Core CPI (L)",
             "Dividend yield - core CPI spread (R)")
legend("bottomright", legend=legend.names,  lwd=1, cex=0.7, col =1:3,lty=1:3)
dev.off()
```

Hm..., flodel got the same answer and I agree that you should write either wrapper around it or write your own savePlot function that works well.

Answer (score 0):

Try `inset=0.05`. This has helped me with similar issues in the past, though I don't have a Win7 machine to test on.